# Using the results from a Quanteda KWIC to count a number of "NOT" occurances (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to capture the number of times keywords show up after "not" words in a large amount of comments to gauge sentiment. To capture the words following the not words I used Quanteda's KWIC and created a dtm for the keywords based on the window afterwords in the KWIC. My issue is that the KWIC dataframe is smaller than the original dataframe and therefore can't find the corresponding occurances.

I have this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(quanteda)

text_column <- c("not safe","not safe and not listening","not safe never patient", "safe","not welcoming","nice people","corporate culture school tacos","successful words words coding","not scary")
test.df <- as.data.frame(text_column)

notwords <- c("not", "never", "don't", "seldom", "won't")

dictionary(list(possafety = c("open","open-minded", "listen*", "safe*", "patien*", "underst*", "willing to help", "helpful", "tight-knit", "hear*", "engage*", "support*", "comfortable", "belong*", "welcom*", "inclu*", "value", "respect*", "always someone you can go to for questions", "accept*")
```

| rownumber | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | not safe |
| 2 | not safe and not listening |
| 3 | not safe and never patient |
| 4 | safe |
| 5 | not welcoming |
| 6 | nice people |
| 7 | corporate culture school tacos |
| 8 | successful words words coding |
| 9 | not scary |

and I want to get this:

| rownumber | text | notpossafe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | not safe | 1 |
| 2 | not safe and not listening | 2 |
| 3 | not safe and never patient | 2 |
| 4 | safe | 0 |
| 5 | not welcoming | 1 |
| 6 | nice people | 0 |
| 7 | corporate culture school tacos | 0 |
| 8 | successful words words coding | 0 |
| 9 | not scary | 0 |

I tried creating a row number variable, filtering the KWIC dataframe for occurances, and used an ifelse statement to verify if the rownumber was found in the dataframe, but that still only gives me a 0 or a 1, and I need to count for instances like in row two and three where there are more than 1 occurance.

```
not.df <- as.data.frame(kwic(test.df$text, pattern = not, window = 2))

not.df$rownumber <- as.numeric(gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*", "\\1", not.df$docname))

corptextnot <- corpus(not.df, text_field = "post")

dtmtextnot <- dfm(corptextnot)

dict_dtmtextnot = dfm_lookup(dtmtextnot, dict, exclusive = TRUE)

nottextdict.df <- as.data.frame(dict_dtmtextnot)

not.df$safe <- nottextdict.df$possafety

not.df <- filter(not.df, safe > 0)

test.df$notpossafe <- ifelse((test.df$rownumber %in% not.df$rownumber), 1,0)
```

This only gives me:

| rownumber | text | notpossafe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | not safe | 1 |
| 2 | not safe and not listening | 1 |
| 3 | not safe and never patient | 1 |
| 4 | safe | 0 |
| 5 | not welcoming | 1 |
| 6 | nice people | 0 |
| 7 | corporate culture school tacos | 0 |
| 8 | successful words words coding | 0 |
| 9 | not scary | 0 |

Is there a way to count the number or occurances that an elseif test is positive and make that the number, or is there a way to find corresponding values between two dataframes of different sizes, or more fundamentally, is there just a better tool to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `stringr` package using `stringr::str_count` and `paste` with `collapse = "|"`:

```
test.df$notpossafe <- stringr::str_count(test.df$text_column, 
                                         paste(notwords, collapse = "|"))
```

Output:

```
#                      text_column notpossafe
# 1                       not safe          1
# 2     not safe and not listening          2
# 3         not safe never patient          2
# 4                           safe          0
# 5                  not welcoming          1
# 6                    nice people          0
# 7 corporate culture school tacos          0
# 8  successful words words coding          0
```

Comment: This works great to count the number of times not words show up, but I need to also see when there is an occurance of any of the "possafe" words from my dictionary in the two words that follow it. I have edited and changed the data frame in my petition to show what I mean. The text in row nine of text_column of the new data ("not scary") also shows a 1 when I need it to be a 0.